# Different behavior of this keyword within angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a Reactive form using angular 2. I'm not able to grab the concept behind why "registerFrom" when I tried to access from createFrom method gives a undefined error but i'm able to access it within the checkPassword method. I'm using the checkpassword method after the view is initialized as an event listener in the template. I'm sure there is some context logic on the way both methods are being used.

Also when i remove registerForm from the validator, just passing component reference to the callback and then try accessing registerForm from the callback. It works perfectly fine

```
export class RegisterComponent {

    registerForm : FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private _authService: AuthService,
        private _f : FormBuilder,
        private _router: Router
    ){
      this.createForm();
    }


    createForm () : void {
        this.registerForm = this._f.group({
            password_group : this._f.group({
                 confirm_password : [
                    '',
                    Validators.compose([
                        CustomValidators.passwordMatch(this.registerForm)
                    ])
                ]
            }),
        })
    }


    checkPassword() : any {
        // Get typed password value
        const password = this.registerForm.get('password_group.password').value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `CustomValidators.passwordMatch(this.registerForm)`.

You're using `this.registerForm` in the same expression that's meant to initialize `this.registerForm`, i.e. before it being initialized.

You can access it as expected, but it's still undefined when you do.

I have no further knowledge about custom validators, but passing in the FormGroup recursively doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Makes sense! The form validator function is just a closure. The return function holds the formgroup. I'm trying to match the password fields. The component reference gives the original password field while the formgroup holds the confirmed password value